# A girl who there was at hospital or A girl who was at hospital

Tags: relative-clauses

```
      1.There was a girl with him.
      2.I remember her.
```

In adjective clauses,which are use to describe 'a girl' here,what structure should we use?

```
     (a) (I remember a girl) who there was with him. or
     (b) (I remember a girl) who was with him.
```

Comment: How about _(c) (I remember a girl) who was there with him_?

Answer (score 1):

(b) is grammatically correct. (a) is not. When we use an expression of the form, "X is there" or "X was there", the word "there" follows the verb. I think that's true regardless of the verb: "I went there", NOT "I there went". "George Washington slept there", etc.

So you could say, "I remember the girl who was there with him" as oerkelens suggests. Or just leave out the word "there". Including it does not substantially change the meaning of the sentence. Mostly it just adds emphasis or perhaps clarification to the place. Depending on context, I suppose without the "there" the sentence could be understood to mean that the girl was with him in general, like she was his assistant or his girlfriend or some such, rather than with him at that particular place.